# Is Klook reliable for buying e-tickets for Singapore's tourist attractions?

Tags: tickets, singapore, scams

I will be visiting Singapore end of January next year. Since the city state has lots of tourist attractions that require entry passes, I am thinking of planning ahead and buy e-tickets before I start my journey.

I came across a website called [www.klook.com](https://www.klook.com/city/6-singapore/), which sells e-tickets at discounted prices. It also has some combo passes. However I am little bit skeptical about the reliability of the website. Even a Google search was not able to resolve my queries. So I thought comments from anyone with first-hand experience will be helpful in this case.

I am looking for answers for these queries: Is the website, www.klook.com, reliable for buying e-tickets for Singapore? Are these tickets genuine and accepted by all places?

Comment: *Even a Google search was not able to resolve my queries* You mean [like this Tripadvisor post](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294211-i642-k8835761-Review_on_Klook-China.html), which is one of the first search results? **You must include those Google search results in your post**, please [edit]. Do not waste our time having to look up information that you already did.

Comment: @JanDoggen That tripadvisor post certainly wouldn't resolve my queries specifically to Klook in Singapore. Most of the post is about China and HK and of the two mentions of Singapore, one is by a person with only two other posts in the forum, both praising klook and the other one looks more legitimate, but a lot of their attraction reviews consist of telling people how convenient it was to book the ticket through klook, so I can understand why one would have doubts about their legitimacy.

Answer (score 1):

I bought a ticket last January 4 and came to my surprise that the attached meal and retail coupon for USS is expired which is not stated on the description before you buy the coupon.  And they still attach the expired coupons on PDF vouchers that makes it more confusing. They will leave you with no options since on their email they said that activities are sold by a third party or local vendor. So better think before purchasing with Klook, Fyi they also reply after one or 2 days. No 24/7 Support.